# ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, tensorflow

I am trying to read multiple csv files and put them into one dataset using pandas and I received the following error message:

**ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
if sys.path[0] == '':**

Furthermore, i noticed that most of my data is labelled as NaN, when in fact, they are numbers. My data consists of financial ratios of companies as well as macroeconomic variables. What am I doing wrong? What other way can I go about reading multiple csv files as one dataset and fix the NaN issue?

Your assistance is highly appreciated.

```
 os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras 

FDataset = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    info = pd.read_csv(f,'Sheet1')
    FDataset = FDataset.append(info)
    
print(FDataset)
```

The output

```
/Users/DubeCM/Documents/Reasearch/Data/Finance_Dataset
/Users/DubeCM/Documents/Reasearch/Data/Finance_Dataset
['TrustCo Group Holdings ltd.csv', 'Standard Bank.csv', 'Nedbank Group.csv', 'PSG Group Limited.csv', 'FinBond Group.csv', 'Zeder Investments Ltd.csv', 'RMB Holdings.csv', 'Vunani Ltd.csv', 'Peregrine Holdings Limited.csv', 'Sasfin Holdings Ltd.csv', 'Hosken Consolidated Investment.csv', 'Efficient Group Ltd.csv', 'Rand Merchnt Holdings.csv', 'African Phoenix Investments Limited.csv', 'FirstRand Limited.csv', 'Capitec Limited.csv', 'Quilter PLC LSE.csv', 'Grand Parade Investments.csv', 'Transaction Capital Ltd.csv', 'Brait Ltd.csv', 'Niveuss.csv', 'StratCorp Ltd.csv', 'Alexander Forbes Ltd.csv', 'Coronation Fund Ltd.csv', 'ABSA Group Ltd.csv', 'PSG Konsult.csv', 'Purple Group Ltd.csv']
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/tenserflowReal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:12: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  if sys.path[0] == '':
   Company Name;TrustCo Group Holdings;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  \
0                 Financial Status;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;     
1   Date;Cash to sales;Cash to total assets;Cash t...     
2   Mar-31 2007;-0,12;-0,05;-0,17;0,17;0,07;0,24;0...     
3   Mar-31 2008;0,08;0,04;0,10;0,25;0,12;0,30;0,44...     
4   Mar-31 2009;0,07;0,04;0,09;0,19;0,12;0,25;0,57...     
..                                                ...     
18                                                NaN     
19                                                NaN     
20                                                NaN     
21                                                NaN     
22                                                NaN     

   Company Name;Standard Bank;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  \
0                                         NaN   
1                                         NaN   
2                                         NaN   
3                                         NaN   
4                                         NaN   
..                                        ...   
18                                        NaN   
19                                        NaN   
20                                        NaN   
21                                        NaN   
22                                        NaN   

   Company Name;Nedbank Group;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  \
0                                         NaN   
1                                         NaN   
2                                         NaN   
3                                         NaN   
4                                         NaN   
..                                        ...   
18                                        NaN   
19                                        NaN   
20                                        NaN   
21                                        NaN   
22                                        NaN   

   Company Name;PSG Group;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  \
0                                      NaN   
1                                      NaN   
2                                      NaN   
3                                      NaN   
4                                      NaN   
..                                     ...   
18                                     NaN   
19                                     NaN   
20                                     NaN   
21                                     NaN   
22                                     NaN   

   Company Name;FinBond Group;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  \
0                                          NaN   
1                                          NaN   
2                                          NaN   
3                                          NaN   
4                                          NaN   
..                                         ...   
18                                         NaN   
19                                         NaN   
20                                         NaN   
21                                         NaN   
22                                         NaN
```

Comment: 1) Your "error" is a warning, you can ignore it. 2) Your data uses comma as decimal separator, pandas expects the dot as default. Add `sep=';'` and `decimal=','` to `read_csv` (and have a look at the other possible attributes in the [function's documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @GPhilo Your suggestion worked, thank you. However, I noticed the layout/order/structure of the data is a bit strange. I think pandas assumed my columns are identical which they are not. Is there a way that I can change the layout or structure of my data?

Comment: Hmmm IIRC Pandas doesn't deal will with CSV files with variable column sizes, it may be necessary to manually parse the CSV in that case